# Jersey Client (JAX-RS 2) not working in OSGI

Tags: jersey-2.0, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I am attempting to install and use Jersey 2 in Karaf version 3.
My features.xml (provisioning) contains the following dependencies:

```java
<bundle>mvn:javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1</bundle>

    <bundle>mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator/2.3.0</bundle>

    <bundle>mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/osgi-resource-locator/1.0.1</bundle>

    <bundle>mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.12</bundle>

    <bundle>mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava/2.12</bundle>

    <bundle>mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils/2.3.0</bundle>

    <bundle>mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api/2.3.0-b10</bundle>

    <bundle>mvn:org.glassfish.hk2.external/javax.inject/2.3.0-b10</bundle>

    <bundle>mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.12</bundle>
```

My code outside of the container posts requests successfully but on using inside the OSGI container fails when attempting to dynamically load the required javax.ws.rs.* implementing classes, as per the edited stack trace below:

```java
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)[:1.7.0_51]
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:107)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:225)
```

The Import-Package of the manifest I am using contains the following:

```java
com.google.common.base;version="[18.0,19)",com.google.common.collect;version="[18.0,19)",com.google.gson;version="[2.2,3)",javax.ws.rs;version="2.0,3)",javax.ws.rs.client;version="[2.0,3)",javax.ws.rs.core;version="[2.0,3)",javax.ws.rs.ext;version="[2.0,3)"
```

How do I bundle the jersey client or my service to avoid the problems caused, for OSGI, of the `Class.forName` used in the `FactoryFinder.newInstance()` method ?

Comment: Try with another jax-rs provider like cxf it's better suited. And maybe ask also on the karaf mailing list

Comment: I had a look at other implementations and but they all end up using javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder to locate the implementing client code and it is FactoryFinder that is breaking OSGI. Apache CXF does have a Proxy approach but the Apache CXF has a big footprint when only an RS client is needed. I've started working with the com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.jersey-all bundle and in this case the Classloader can locate the client implementation but Karaf (at least) doesn't provide javax.annotation Commons 2.0 out the box, so it seems non-standard karaf build is required to get it working.

Comment: In the later case, add the required bundle for javax.annotation 2.0